# How do you add dataclasses as valid index values to a plotly chart?

Tags: plotly-python

I am trying to switch from the `matplotlib` pandas plotting backend to `plotly`. However, I am being held back by a common occurrence of this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type Quarter is not JSON serializable
```

Where `Quarter` is a dataclass in my codebase.

For a minimal example, consider:

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    val:int
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [Foo(i) for i in range(10)], 'y':list(range(10))})

df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y')
```

As expected, the above returns:

```
TypeError: Object of type Foo is not JSON serializable
```

Now, I don't expect `plotly` to be magical, but adding a `__float__` magic method allows the `Foo` objects to be used with the `matplotlib` backend:

```
# This works
@dataclass
class Foo:
    val:int
    
    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.val)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [Foo(i) for i in range(10)], 'y':list(range(10))})

df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y')
```

How can I update my `dataclass` to allow for it to be used with the `plotly` backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get **pandas** to cast to `float` before invoking plotting backend.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd

@dataclass
class Foo:
    val:int
    
    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.val)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [Foo(i) for i in range(10)], 'y':list(range(10))})
df["x"].astype(float)

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

df.assign(x=lambda d: d["x"].astype(float)).plot.scatter(x='x', y='y')
```

#### monkey patching

- if you don't want to change code, you can monkey patch the **plotly** implementation of **pandas** plotting API
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#plotting-backends

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd
import wrapt, json
import plotly

@wrapt.patch_function_wrapper(plotly, 'plot')
def new_plot(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
    try:
        json.dumps(args[0][kwargs["x"]])
    except TypeError:
        args[0][kwargs["x"]] = args[0][kwargs["x"]].astype(float)
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    


@dataclass
class Foo:
    val:int
    
    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.val)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [Foo(i) for i in range(10)], 'y':list(range(10))})
df["x"].astype(float)

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm currently doing - but it's painful to write this every time. 
I could register a `.px.` dataframe accessor that first casts all my custom `dtype` items to float and then invokes `.plot` ....

Comment: have provided a monkey patching approach as well